# What's the difference between clicking the red close (x) button, and calling .Close()?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms app, and in my app, i have a custom form I created.  This custom from has the default close, minimize, and maximize buttons in the top right corner.  If I close the form using the default red x button, it closes fine with no problems.  However, if I try to close the form by calling .Close() on the form, it throws an unhandled InvalidOperationException exception.

What is the difference between calling .Close(), and clicking that button?  Why does clicking the button work fine, but calling .Close() throw the exception?

Comment: When you receive an exception you could easily see the stack trace. This info is fundamental to understand what is causing the exception. You could add that info here

Comment: @Steve there is no stack trace.  The application doesn't crash or throw the exception.  The only way I know it is happening is because the output shows the line:  "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: @Steve also, i know it's happening because the form doesn't close.

Comment: @TylerJones It's possible you are suppressing the exception then. Are there any try/catch clauses that you could comment out during your testing?  It may be necessary to show some of your code...

Comment: @NathanA no, there are no try/catches surrounding any of the code in question.

Comment: where do you call `this.Close();`. on the mainthread? please show the part you are calling the method.

Comment: public void WebBrowserCallback()
        {
            if (_cefBrowser != null)
            {
                _cefBrowser.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: .Hide() throws the exact same error.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question?  I need some help here.  This is a programming question.  Isn't stackoverflow for programming questions?  This is not a networking question or english language question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TOOLS->Spy++` to log the window messages.

From:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,b6605a5b113b45f7

The `Form.Close()` method calls:

```
closeReason = CloseReason.UserClosing;
SendMessage(NativeMethods.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

Also, try searching for the exception message:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Form+C%23+A+first+chance+exception+of+type++webbrowser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Came up with this links:

[C# : "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393092/c-sharp-a-first-chance-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception)