# Find source of Exception shown in VS output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

When running my application in VS2013 I get the exceptions:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

and

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

This exceptions are caught anywhere since my application does not crash, everything works "normal".
But I would really like to find the code section causing this exceptions to solve this.

What can I do to find out which part of my code throws this exception or where it happens. Is there a way to show/visualize this in VS? Debugger options?

Comment: This post will answer your query,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393092/c-sharp-a-first-chance-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception

Comment: You can get the debugger to stop by ticking the Thrown checkbox.  Actually seeing the code that threw the exception, that is much less likely to happen since you don't have the source code for mscorlib.dll.  You'll have to reverse-engineer it from the content of the Call Stack debugger window and the Reference Source web site.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> What can I do to find out which part of my code throws this exception or where it happens. Is there a way to show/visualize this in VS? Debugger options?

In Visual Studio, choose **Debug** then **Exceptions**.

In the **Exceptions** window, tick **Thrown** on the **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** row.

[image]

Click **OK**.

Now whenever an exception is thrown, the debugger will break on the offending line.  You can also expand the selection to only include the exceptions of interest.

### Visual Studio 2017

You can find this under **Debug.Windows.Exception Settings**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This window has been moved in VS2015. It's located at Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings.

Comment: Thanks @Daryl.  Another fine example of _who moved my cheese?!_.  ;)

Comment: I also didn't realize until today that there is a difference between these check boxes being "filled in" vs "checked" when they have sub-items.  I guess filled in means that you can check the sub-items.  Checked means all sub-items are also checked.  That explains why VS wasn't breaking on any exceptions for me.

Comment: @drewmerk yes that’s right.  I think I first saw the concept with installers and choosing which components to install.

Comment: If only every SO comment/solution was as detailed and helpful as this one.  Kudos and thank you, @mickyd.

Comment: @Chase Thanks very much!  My pleasure :)